# How to generate permanent access token for WhatsApp Cloud API integration

Tags: whatsapp, facebook-access-token, whatsapi

I'm using WhatsApp Cloud API Integration for our company use case and all functionality will be server-to-server API call and I have to generate a Permanent token to call the WhatsApp API to send the message. I have submitted a request to get advance access to whatsapp_business_messaging but it got rejected as we do not have any frontend UI to showcase the implementation. Facebook support team said I do not need advance access if we are implementing WhatsApp API for our own use case. We have also generated the permanent key by creating a system user from the Facebook Business dashboard but the API throws an error that this key does not have permission.

Please guide me on how can a get approval or get a permanent access token to use the WhatsApp Cloud API Integration.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

On your business setting go to the User(left side menu) and create a system user there. and there you can create the permanent access token.

Comment: Is there anything else you have to do first for the system to create the permanent access token? When I try to create a system user, I get an error: `You are temporarily blocked from creating a user`

Comment: @Youzef I'm also facing the same, did you find any other way to get an access token?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I closed that project. You could try on the facebook's whatsapp forums